Find Gal($f$) and give the diagram of the intermediate fields of $f=X^4-4X^2+5$
Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f=X^4-4X^2+5$. Find the Galoisgroup of $f$ and give the diagram of all the intermediate fields.
We know that $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2+i},\sqrt{2-i})$. I have already proven that Gal$(f)\cong D_4$. I know that there exists functions $\sigma,\rho$ to make this diagram, but i can't figure out what they exactly are.
Can someone help me?

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal}$
If $u=\sqrt{2+i}$, then the roots of $f$ are $$u,-u,\frac{\sqrt{5}}{u},-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{u},$$ which we will label $1,2,3,4$ respectively.
Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},i)$, then $L$ is the splitting field of the irreducible polynomial $x^2-2-i$ over $K$. The automorphism of $K$ given by
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{5}&\mapsto-\sqrt{5}\\
i&\mapsto i
\end{align*}
leaves the polynomial $x^2-2-i$ fixed and so it extends to an automorphism $\rho$ of $L$ with $\rho(u)=u$. The automorphism $\rho$ corresponds to the permutation $(34)$ in $S_4$.
Of the three copies of $D_4$ in $S_4$, only one contains $(34)$. Namely
$$\left\langle{(1324),(34)}\right\rangle.$$
Therefore, $\Gal(f)=\left\langle{\sigma,\rho}\right\rangle$ where
\begin{align*}
\sigma(u)&=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{u},\\
\sigma(\sqrt{5})&=-\sqrt{5},\\
\rho(u)&=u,\\
\rho(\sqrt{5})&=-\sqrt{5}.
\end{align*}
You may then use the Galois Correspondence to find the intermediate field lattice.

Thank you very much!
